# How to save a standalone R environment object

Tags: r

I am spending already hours trying to make this work and feel that I am missing something simple:

```
my_env = new.env(hash = TRUE, parent = .GlobalEnv)
my_env[['echo']] <- function(x) {x}
my_env[['echo']](123)
[1] 123
my_env$echo(123)
[1] 123
save(my_env, file = "MyEnv.RData", envir = .GlobalEnv)
loaded_env <- load(file = "MyEnv.RData",envir = .GlobalEnv)
typeof(loaded_env)
[1] "character"
```

When I save entire workspace, functions are saved and then loaded back (after I close/open R Studio). But here, `save()` and/or `load()` do not work, and I have only a string in my environment after loading.

How could I save a separate environment object to a file, not a complete workspace? I then need all objects inside that environment (`my_env`) to be loaded into .GlobalEnv in another session.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**1) save/load** Your code does work in that `my_env` is restored; however, `load` returns the names of the restored objects, not the objects themselves.  The objects themselves are silently restored as a side effect rather than via the return value.

```
save(my_env, file = "MyEnv.RData")
rm(my_env)
nms <- load("MyEnv.RData")
nms
## [1] "my_env"
my_env
## [1] <environment: 0x000000000bfa5c70>
```

**2) saveRDS/readRDS** You can alternately use `saveRDS` and `readRDS` to save and restore single objects. In that case `readRDS` return the object itself rather than its name unlike `load`.

```
saveRDS(my_env, file = "MyEnv.RData")
rm(my_env)
my_env <- readRDS("MyEnv.RData")
my_env
## <environment: 0x000000000bfb45f8>
```

**3) save/attach** Another possibility is to place `MyEnv.RData` on the search path rather than in the global environment:

```
save(my_env, file = "MyEnv.RData")
rm(my_env)
attach("MyEnv.RData")
my_env
## <environment: 0x000000000b072188>
```

**Note:** If you wish to load the contents of `my_env` into the global environment rather than loading `my_env` itself you will have to copy the contents out:

```
for(el in ls(my_env)) assign(el, get(el, my_env))
```

Comment: Thanks! RDS works perfectly! How could I serialize an environment object to a char vector? There is a `serialize` function - does it return the same binary format as if I would read a file from RDS?

Comment: `save`, `saveRDS` and `serialize` all have an `ascii` argument.

Comment: so if all arguments are the same, all three functions return binary compatible formats?

Comment: Cool! Thanks for your help and detailed explanation of the three options.